# How to get the percentage that a child element is proportioned to a super parent

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to stack divs inside a div parent container. The parent div container is also a child or inside a parent container.

My problem is that when stacking the divs as pixels everything is OK; however, if i need to slip one in under or in between the stack of divs sometimes I loose a pixel. I am aware that it is not possible to have 0.3232 pixel and I am assuming that I am loosing a pixel in the decimal place.

I have a constant set as var PIXELS_PER_FOOT =25;

If I have a structure like the following how can I set the percentage of a child element proportional to the superparent?

```
  <div id="superParent" height='500px'       OR 20 Feet     >



    <div id="anotherParent" height="300px"   OR 12 Feet     >


    <div id="aChild" height=If this div is  3 Feet 
                             I need to get the percentage of 3 foot from 20 foot and        
                              apply                             
                              that percentage to its parent or                 
                               what I am calling the anotherParent


   </div>
   </div>
```

So if 3/20 = 15%. I need to get 12/20 =60%, and this is where I get lost. Because applying 15% to the aChild element would not be correct since its parent is not the number I am getting the main percentages from.

I cannot use jQuery for this.

Answer (score 0):

I already have access to each parent's pixel, because in my loop the pixels on each object are set from the top down based on it's parent's height, so it does not matter where i am at in the loop I can always have a way to set the percentage of a child object as long as I set the child object's height before I attempt to get the percentage.

```
this.heightPercent = (this.heightPixels / that.parent.size.heightPixels) * 100;
```